# Interpreting $4D$ massive scalar momentum space action as a gauge-field action in 1D?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, momentum, field-theory, fourier-transform

Consider the following action for massive scalar as follows

$$S = \int d^4x \left(-\frac{1}{2}\partial^{\mu}\phi\partial_{\mu}\phi-\frac{1}{2}m^2\phi^2\right) \tag{1}$$
with Minkowski signature $(-,+,+,+)$.
Now, I do a Fourier transform of the spatial coordinates to obtain
$$S = \int dt d^3k \left[\frac{1}{2}\dot{\phi}(t, \vec{k})\dot{\phi}(t, -\vec{k})-\frac{1}{2}(|\vec{k}|^2+m^2)\phi(t,-\vec{k})\phi(t,\vec{k})\right] .\tag{2}$$
Now, I wish to interpret the above as an action for a trivial bundle $E = \mathbb{R}\times F$ where $F$ is the constant 3D vector space. I wish to interpret $|\vec{k}| dt$ as the connection one-form on this trivial fibre with the covariant derivative
$$\nabla = d \pm |\vec{k}| dt$$ such that
$$\nabla\phi(t, \pm \vec{k}) = d\phi(t, \pm \vec{k})\pm |\vec{k}|\phi(t, \pm \vec{k}) dt$$
so that we have
$$\nabla\phi(t, \vec{k})\wedge * \nabla\phi(t, -\vec{k}) = dt \left[\dot{\phi}(t, \vec{k})\dot{\phi}(t, -\vec{k})-|\vec{k}|^2\phi(-\vec{k})\phi(\vec{k})\right]$$

Can someone comment on whether my application of the trivial fibre to this case is sound?

Addendum: Can someone comment on the following? If I interpret $\vec{k}$ as a section on $F$ then does the following make sense

$$\nabla \vec{k} = dt A^{i}_j k^j =  |\vec{k}|\vec{k} dt$$ where $A^i_j = |\vec{k}|\delta^i_j$ where $A^i_j$ is the connection on this trivial constant vector space?

Also, perhaps, one can interpret $\int d^3k f(t, \vec{k})g(t, -\vec{k}) = \text{Tr}_k[f(t, \vec{k}) g(t,-\vec{k})]$ so that the full action looks like
$$S = -\frac{1}{2}\int_{\mathbb{R}} \left(\text{Tr}_k[\nabla\phi(\vec{k})\wedge \nabla(-\vec{k})] + m^2 \text{Tr}_k[\phi(\vec{k})\wedge (-\vec{k})]\right)$$ very much like an action of a scalar field in fundamental representation coupled to a gauge field?

Comment: By definition covariant derivatives on a scalar field are just the usual differential. A connection becomes necessary when the field is vector (or generally tensor valued). Perhaps you are rather interested in the linear/non linear sigma models?